# Find "x" in the right triangle $ABC$, right angle at $B$.

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

My progress:
[image]

I extended the lines and formed an equilateral triangle but an equation is still missing

$x+\theta = 60^\text{o}\\
x+ \alpha = 50^\text{o}\\
\ldots\ldots$

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{BH}{CH}.$$

Comment: @Pythagoras  ..I didn't understand this proportion...are the triangles ABH and AHC similar? By which theorem??

Comment: It is the angle bisector theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem

Comment: It's there in red, by "E".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible path with Euclidean geometry, also following in part your construction.

[image]

1. Construct equilateral triangle $\triangle CEF$.
2. Produce $AC$ to $G$ so that $\measuredangle CFG = 20^\circ$.
3. Observe that $\triangle AFG$ is isosceles, and so is $\triangle CGF$.
4. By SAS criterion, show that $\triangle AGH \cong \triangle AFH$ and $\triangle CEH \cong\triangle CFH$.
5. Conclude that $\triangle GHF$ and $\triangle EHF$ are isosceles and furthermore $\triangle GHF \cong \triangle EHF$ (SSS criterion).
6. Thus $FH$ bisects $\angle GFA$.
7. Conclude that $\measuredangle HEC = 20^\circ$.

Comment: Nice solution - How did you make the diagram? Was it via asymptote?

Comment: @TheBestMagician, thanks! It's Geogebra.

Answer (score 1):

By the law of sines in $\triangle EHC$, $EH=\frac{HC}{2\sin x}$. Since $\angle CEB=60$, $EH=\frac{BH}{\sin(60-x)}$. Thus $HC\sin(60-x)=2BH\sin x$. Hence
$$BC=HC\left(1+\frac{\sin(60-x)}{2\sin x}\right)$$
But notice that $AB\tan 10=BH$. Thus
$$BC=AB\tan 20=BH\frac{\tan 20}{\tan 10}=HC\frac{\sin(60-x)\tan 20}{2\sin x\tan 10}$$
Equating the two expressions for $BC$, we get that
$$\frac{2\sin x+\sin(60-x)}{2\sin x}=\frac{\sin(60-x)\tan 20}{2\sin x\tan 10}$$
$$2\sin x\tan 10+\sin(60-x)\tan 10=\sin(60-x)\tan 20$$
Can you finish from here? (All angles are in degrees)

Comment: @TheBestMagician...thanks for help but i need a geometric resolution without using trigonometry