# Find $x$ in the figure

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, angle

> Find $x$ in the figure.
>
> [image: another adventitious triangle]
>
> <sup>(Answer: $20^\circ$)</sup>

My progress:

Let $P$ such that $PDHC$ is cyclic.

[image: attempt]

$\angle ACH = 180^\circ-20^\circ-90^\circ = 70^\circ\implies AHC = 100^\circ$

$\therefore ∠PDC=∠AHC=100^\circ$ and $∠PDA=180^\circ-60^\circ-100^\circ=20^\circ$

$\therefore ∠BDH+x=60^\circ$

If I find out $\angle DCP$, ends...??

Comment: Didn't you already posted the same problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212239/find-x-in-the-right-triangle-abc-right-angle-at-b/4212405#4212405

Comment: @dfnu  thanks I had looked for it but I can't find it..here is another solution

Comment: If you have solved angle chasing problems relating to $80-80-20$ triangle, this question follows very similar construction, once you convert it into an  $80-80-20$ triangle. Here is a link to many related questions: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/IndexToClassical.shtml

Comment: @MathLover thanks for in..great material..if it wasn't abusive you could look at this question...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217903/calculate-angle-x-in-the-figure at the time it was requested but I would like to know if there is a less trigonometric solution

Comment: @petaarantes sure I will look at it as soon as I have some time with me...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find "x" in the right triangle $ABC$, right angle at $B$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212239/find-x-in-the-right-triangle-abc-right-angle-at-b)

Comment: @ACB  yes ..I know..i just post another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leveraging colleague Vasily's perpendicular idea:

Let $P$ be a point on $AH$ such that the quadrilateral $PDHC$ is cyclic.

[image: enter image description here, so enter]

$\angle ACH = 180^\circ-20^\circ-90^\circ = 70^\circ\implies AHC = 100^\circ.$

$\therefore  ∠PDC=∠AHC=100^\circ$ and $∠PDA=180^\circ-60^\circ-100^\circ=20^\circ.$

Trace $DE \perp AH ~ (E \in AC).$

$G=DC \cap AH$ and $F =DE \cap AH.$

$\angle DPG = 30^\circ$

$\therefore \angle DGP = 180^\circ - 100^\circ-30^\circ = 50^\circ \implies \angle FDG = 40^\circ$

$\therefore \boxed{\color{red}x = 60^\circ-40^\circ = 20^\circ}$

Comment: You've missed the proof of Vasily's point.

Answer (score 3):

Either you have incorrect answer, or you marked the wrong angle. The angle of $x$ should be $20^\circ$.

Hint: Put point $E$  on $AC$ so $AH\perp DE$ and prove that $\triangle HDE$ is equilateral.

Answer (score 1):

$\angle CDH = x$ cannot possibly be $40^\circ$.  That would imply $\angle HDB = \angle CDB - \angle CDH = 60^\circ - 40^\circ = 20^\circ$, which would in turn imply that $DH || AC$, hence $D$ is the midpoint of $AB$.  But since $\angle ACD = 40^\circ > 30^\circ = \angle CDB$, this is impossible, since the angle bisector of $\angle ACB$ cuts $AB$ at some point $F$ such that $AF > BF$, which would mean $D$ is between $A$ and $F$, contradicting $\angle ACD > \angle CDB$.

The correct value for $x$ is $20^\circ$.  I do not have an elementary geometric solution, but a trigonometric solution is possible.